# PHP find keyword and delete entire line which has the matching keyword

Tags: php, function, csv

I'm writing a php script for my form-mail script to post all emails sent to a pipe delimited csv file, I then display the csv file via a php array. I need to allow the user to delete an entry by passing the id/invoice number of the listing which is the last or 22nd field in the line from that listing to a delete function as shown below, but it's deleting everything in the csv file, not just that line. Here's my code. I compare the id passed to the invoicenumber if it matches it should delete that line and put the rest back in, but it's deleting all entries.

I made your corrections as follows but it's still wiping out all entries:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "Delete")
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $fptemp = fopen('data-temp.csv', "a+");
    if (($handle = fopen($dataFile, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data= fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if ($id != $data[22])
            {
                fputcsv($data);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fptemp);
        unlink($dataFile);
        rename('data-temp.csv',$dataFile);
    }
}
```

so I have the following entries in my csv file

```
1346785585|Martha|Stewart|karen@someplace.com|555-444-2222|578 dude rd|dude|TN|57660|usa|Do it Yourself Cooking Book||389|12|||360|12|Credit Card|www.something.com||98.143.4.228|6c67b98 
1346785588|Karen|b|karen@someplace.com|555-444-2222|578 dude rd|dude|TN|57660|usa|Do it Yourself WebSite||389|12|||360|12|Credit Card|www.something.com||98.143.4.228|464b4ec
```

I want to find invoice number which is the very last field in the line, so let's say I want to find "464b4ec" and delete the entire entry consisting of

```
1346785588|Karen|b|karen@someplace.com|555-444-2222|578 dude rd|dude|TN|57660|usa|Do it Yourself WebSite||389|12|||360|12|Credit Card|www.something.com||98.143.4.228|464b4ec
```

I want to leave all other entries alone, how would I do that?

Comment: Why are you overwriting `$id` inside your loop?

Answer (score 1):

Two fixes. As others have pointed out, you're using `$id` for two things. Change:

```
$id= fgetcsv($handle)
```

to:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')
```

Also, when you're writing the output file, you're wrapping an array in another array, which isn't needed. Change:

```
$list = array($data);
fputcsv($fptemp, $list);
```

to:

```
fputcsv($data);
```

Comment: Does it work? I can't tell anything about the code in your comment without proper formatting.

Comment: You can't format in comment boxes. Edit the original question.

Comment: oh, ok (I'm new to posting here)

Comment: See my latest edit. You forgot to specify the field delimiter character in your `fgetcsv` call, so it defaults to comma.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

a) fgetcsv() returns an array of fields from the line of csv data just read. You compare that entire array to a (single?) item, `$data[22]`. Unless data[22] is itself an array, this is not going to work as you expect

if $data is NOT an array, it'd be treated as a string, and you're comparing $id against the 22nd character in the string.

b) $data is already an array, which you then wrap in another array - `array($data)`. So... i'm guessing $data is actually a string.

c) since you only do fputcsv if your id v.s data comparison DOESN'T match, you aren't deleting just a field - you skip the entire line. To delete the 22nd item in the array only, it'd have to be

```
if ($id == $data[22) {
   unset($data[22]);
}
fputcsv($fptemp, $data);
```

d) and as Jack points out in his comment , you're overwriting $id in your loop, so the $_POST value you had in it is destroyed the moment you read your first line of csv data.

Comment: "you aren't deleting just a field - you skip the entire line" -- that's what he said he wants to do. He's just using the field as the criteria for whether to delete it.